# sorting input in lexicographical order with dynamic array

Tags: c

I try to write a program which reads in single signs from a keyboard. If they are not already present they should be stored in a array.

After that, all signs get sorted and all already occurring signs are printed.

edit: if the entered sign already exists it is not added. The array should only contain unique elements.

The array starts with a size of `0` and should double its capacity every time it is full when a new character arrives.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work correctly. If I look via the debugger it looks like the values get stored one after another, but as soon as the second sign arrives the program crashes in `print` / `qsort`.

Am I doing something wrong in the allocation?

Also if you have other recommendations for improve this code please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reserve_space(char **c, int *capacity);
void print_signs(char **signs, const int max_size);
int cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs);

// allocates factor 2 of the current capacity
void reserve_space(char **c, int *capacity) {
    char *new_c;

    if (*capacity == 0) {       // allocate the first time
        *capacity = 1;
        *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((*capacity)));
    } else {
        *capacity *= 2;     // double the new capacity
        new_c = realloc(*c, sizeof(char) * (*capacity));
        *c = new_c;
    }
    return;
}

void print_signs(char **signs, const int sz) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        printf("%i %c\n", *signs[i], *signs[i]);            // crash in read after array has 2 signs???
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) {
    char left = *((char *)lhs);
    char right = *((char *)rhs);

    if (left < right) return -1;
    if (left > right) return  1;

    return 0;  /* left == right */
}

int main() {
    int capacity = 0;       // allocated space 
    int sz = 0;             // space currently "filled" with signs
    char *signs = 0;

    char ch = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        int pos = 0;

        if (sz == capacity)
            reserve_space(&signs, &capacity);

        for (pos = 0; pos < sz; ++pos) {
            if (signs[pos] == ch)
                continue;   /* indicating element exists already */
        }

        if (pos == capacity - 1)    // -1 because last sign must be terminating '\0'
            reserve_space(&signs, &capacity);

        signs[pos] = ch;    //adding new sign at pos of "old" \0
        ++sz;
        ++pos;
        signs[pos] = '\0';  //adding new terminating \0

        qsort(&signs, sz - 1, sizeof(char), cmp);

        print_signs(&signs, sz);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I want to say thank you for actually using a debugger and adding the information you did.  You should get a good answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Quickly - if your size is "1" and you set the `\0`' to `++sz`, you have written to bad memory.  You need to track the `\0` character in your size for the array.

Comment: `qsort(&signs, sz-1, sizeof(char), cmp);` is suspicious, I'd expect `qsort(signs, ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in `print_sign`: the order of precedence between `*` and `[]` is such that `*signs[i]` is parsed as `*(signs[i])` instead of `(*signs)[i]` as you assume.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void print_signs(char **signs, const int sz) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        printf("%i %c\n", (*signs)[i], (*signs)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

There is actually no reason to pass the address of the pointer to this function. It can be simplified into:

```
void print_signs(char *signs, const int sz) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        printf("%i %c\n", signs[i], signs[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And called as `print_signs(signs, sz);`

There are many other issues in your code:

- `ch` should be defined as `int`.
- the `continue` statement in the lookup loop is moot, you should instead write the loop as

  ```
  for (pos = 0; pos < sz; ++pos) {
      if (signs[pos] != ch)
          break;   /* indicating element exists already */
  }
  if (pos < sz)
      continue;
  ```
- there are off by 1 errors in the rest if the `main` function
- the comparison function is broken too.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reserve_space(char **c, int *capacity);
void print_signs(const char *signs, int max_size);
int cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs);

// allocates factor 2 of the current capacity
void reserve_space(char **c, int *capacity) {
    if (*capacity == 0) {   // allocate the first time
        *capacity = 1;
        *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((*capacity)));
    } else {
        *capacity *= 2;     // double the new capacity
        *c = realloc(*c, sizeof(char) * (*capacity));
    }
}

void print_signs(const char *signs, int sz) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        printf("%i %c\n", signs[i], signs[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int cmp(void const *lhs, void const *rhs) {
    unsigned char left = *(const unsigned char *)lhs;
    unsigned char right = *(const unsigned char *)rhs;

    if (left < right) return -1;
    if (left > right) return  1;
    return 0;  /* left == right */
}

int main() {
    int sz = 0;             // space currently "filled" with signs
    int capacity = 0;       // allocated space 
    char *signs = NULL;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        int pos = 0;

        for (pos = 0; pos < sz; ++pos) {
            if (signs[pos] == ch)
                break;
        }
        if (pos < sz)
            continue;  // character is already in the array

        if (sz == capacity)
            reserve_space(&signs, &capacity);

        signs[sz] = ch;    // append the sign in the array
        sz++;
        // '\0' terminator is not needed as array is not used as a string
    }
    qsort(signs, sz, sizeof(char), cmp);
    print_signs(signs, sz);
    free(signs);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the statement gets changed to break it would still add the sign already existing or not? it should be unique. no sign shouldnt be twice. i think i forgot to mention it i will edit the question

Comment: ok i didnt saw that statement at first. now it makes sense. just one thing shouldnt it be           [code] free(size); [/code] ?

Comment: Good and correct use of `unsigned char` and `const` in `const unsigned char *` in `cmp()`.

Comment: unfortunately youre code seems to be still buggy. i tested it with input `hello 1234` and terminated with `strg + z` (windows) to simulate     EOF. all it puts is the hello. in the debugger it looks like it only adds the first h.

Comment: @chqrlie it looks like only the first time it enters the assign with youre logic. I included 'stdbool.h' and changed the logic to   bool is_already_in = false;

  `for (pos = 0; pos < sz; ++pos) {
   if (signs[pos] == ch) {
    is_already_in = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (is_already_in)
   continue;  // character is already in the array`